# How to get all indices for the maximum value in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, indexing

I have an array of numbers, and the maximum value might occurrence more than once.

How can we get a collection of indices of all the occurrences of the maximum value in the array?

For example, for the following array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array((1,2,3,2,3,2,1,3))
```

the result should be `[2, 4, 7]` (or an equivalent array or tuple).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array((1,2,3,2,3,2,1,3))

occurences = np.where(a == a.max())

# occurences == array([2, 4, 7])
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is true with more recent versions, but with v1.4.0, should have `occurences = np.where(a == a.max())[0]` such that you get an array rather than a tuple in occurences.