# How to find last occurrence of maximum value in a numpy.ndarray

Tags: numpy, scipy

I have a numpy.ndarray in which the maximum value will mostly occur more than once.

EDIT: This is subtly different from [numpy.argmax: how to get the index corresponding to the *last* occurrence, in case of multiple occurrences of the maximum values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038975) because the author says

> Or, even better, is it possible to get a list of indices of all the occurrences of the maximum value in the array?

whereas in my case getting such a list may prove *very* expensive

Is it possible to find the index of the last occurrence of the maximum value by using something like `numpy.argmax`? I want to find *only* the index of the last occurrence, not an array of all occurrences (since several hundreds may be there)

For example this will return the index of the first occurrence ie 2

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([0,0,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,2])
print np.argmax(a)
```

However I want it to output 5.

Comment: possible duplicate of [numpy.argmax: how to get the index corresponding to the *last* occurrence, in case of multiple occurrences of the maximum values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038975/numpy-argmax-how-to-get-the-index-corresponding-to-the-last-occurrence-in-ca)

Comment: The author there wants the index of all occurrences, and the solution given there `occurences = np.where(a == a.max())` will generate an array of all maximum values which may be very expensive in my case

Comment: though the answer addresses only how to get all occurrences, the questioner asked for both, hence "possible duplicate" rather than "duplicate".

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`numpy.argmax` only returns the index of the first occurrence. You could apply `argmax` to a reversed view of the array:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,0,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,2])
b = a[::-1]
i = len(b) - np.argmax(b) - 1
i     # 5
a[i:] # array([4, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

Note numpy doesn't copy the array but instead creates a view of the original with a [stride](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#internal-memory-layout-of-an-ndarray) that accesses it in reverse order.

```
id(a) == id(b.base) # True
```

Comment: Is there no equivalent function that gets the index of the last occurrence? Also wont reversing the array be an O(n) operation, not to mention doubling memory usage?

Comment: Doubtful there's another function, since the reverse view is quite efficient.