# Find the last occurrence of the max value in a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find the last occurring max value in an array. The following code is what I have thus far:

```
a = np.matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [99, 7, 8, 9, 10], [99, 12, 13, 99, 15], [16, 99, 18, 19, 20], [99, 22, 23, 24, 99]])
m, n = a.shape
out = np.full((n), np.nan)

for i in range(n):
    out[i] = np.argwhere(a[:, i] == 99)
```

However it keeps on popping up with an error as shown:

The aim of this code is to go through each column and find the last occurrence of the maximum value ( in this case 99 ) so the result should look something like [4, 3, 0, 2, 4]

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: This may be of help https://stackoverflow.com/a/8768734/10191959

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are close

```
for i in range(n):
    # first find max value and then the indexes of that value
    z = np.argwhere(a[:, i] == np.amax(a[:, i]))
    w, _ = z.shape
    # extract the position of last max value
    out[i] = z[w - 1, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks just what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

No loop is necessary.

`argmax` by default finds the first index of the maximum element, but we can use `flip` to change that. It also by default finds the maximum of the entire multidimensional array, but if passed an axis it will only do  it on that axis:

```
out = a.shape[1] - 1 - np.argmax(np.flip(a, axis=1), axis=1)
out = np.array(out).ravel()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use argmax, but you must reverse the array order and the subtract it from the array item count -1.  argmax finds the index of the first max occurrence.

```
a = np.matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [99, 7, 8, 9, 10], [99, 12, 13, 99, 15], [16, 99, 18, 19, 20], [99, 22, 23, 24, 99]])

out = np.full((n), np.nan)
val = np.full((n), np.nan)

for i in range(n):
     col=a[:,i]
     #argmax finds the max first occurrence, so reverse the col
     col=col[::-1]
     index = len(col) - np.argmax(col) - 1
     val[i]=a[index,i]
     out[i] = index

 print(out)
```

output:

```
 [4. 3. 4. 2. 4.]
```